# How to search Links list from wiki link?

Tags: 2010, wiki-pages, sitepages, links-list, links

### Background

From a default Team Site, I am trying to link to an item in a list from a Site Page (with wiki support). Normally, I would search for an item easily by typing `[[List:<list name>/<item name>]]` and it would link to the item. On saving, it will replace the entire text with the item ID and its title. For example, the above would become `[[List:List/1|Item ID 1 Title]]`.

Typically `<item name>` corresponds to the *Title* column of a list (as I am told, every list creates this column of single line of text and it cannot be removed only renamed).

### Problem

As an exception, the built-in list Links does not have a title (by default it has *URL*, *Notes*, *Created By*, and *Modified By*). When adding the link as described above, it does not complete the search nor can it link properly.

### Example

For example I have a Site Pages libary, a Tasks list, and a Links list (added by default for a team site template). I have an item **Link to Links lists** in the Tasks list and an item in the Links list to **Google**.

From any site page, when linking to the item in Tasks works as expected; when linking to the Links list, it has no idea.

[image: Linking to list items from site page]

How can I create links to this special list so that this search function knows what I'm trying to link?

### Updates

1. I added a *Title* column to the existing list - checking required and enforce unique values. The link(s) still do not appear in the linking search.
2. In the interim, I created a view that shows the ID column. Even this approach only replaces the text with the ID value and is still not helpful for collaborators.
3. I've tried searching by the URL itself, but it does not appear in the search query.
4. After reading about why [Links lists don't have titles](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/02/sharepoint-search-tip-search-for-where.html), I tried searching by the *Notes* column. Nothing appears either.
5. As a workaround, I created a new custom list that includes the title by default. I will put this into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround and works for my situation:

**Don't use the built-in Links list.**

The Links template list does not have a title column (rather it is [difficult to query](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/02/sharepoint-search-tip-search-for-where.html)) nor does it use other columns for its search queries (I tried searching by *URL* and *Notes* columns).

Create a new custom list, add a **Hyperlink** and **Multiple Lines of Text** column, and you have a searchable list.

Now you can add the links manually or export the current list into an Excel file to later import it into the new list.